# Is the intersection of two locally compact subspaces locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Taking *locally compact* as such that every point has a local base of compact neighborhoods, is the intersection of two locally compact subspaces locally compact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let 
$$X=\bigl((\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\times\{-1,1\}\bigr)\cup\bigl( \mathbb Q\times\{0\}\bigr)  $$
where we declare $U\subseteq X$ open iff $U=(V\times\{-1,0,1\})\cap X$ for some open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$.
Admittedly, $X$ is not Hausdorff. But it contains two subsets $(\mathbb R\times\{0,1\})\cap X$ and $(\mathbb R\times\{0,-1\})\cap X$ that are homeomorphic to the locally compact space $\mathbb R$, whereas their intersection $(\mathbb R\times\{0,\})\cap X$ is homomorphic to the not locally compact space $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You can make it $T_1$: it still works if you replace this topology by its join with the cofinite topology.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the following.

The answer is positive for Hausdorff spaces. Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space, $A$, $B$ be locally compact subspaces of the space $X$, and $x\in A\cap B$ be an arbitrary point. Let $U\ni x$ be a compact neighborhood of the point $x$ in the space $A$ and $V\ni x$ be a compact neighborhood of the point $x$ in the space $B$. Then $U\cap V$ is a neighborhood of the point $x$ in the space $A\cap B$. Since the space $X$ is Hausdorff, both sets $U$ and $V$ are closed in the space $X$. Hence $U\cap V$ is a closed subset of the space $X$ too. Then  $U\cap V$ is a closed subsets of a Hausdorff compact space $U$ too, so a space $U\cap V$ is compact.

Comment: Could you explain why are $U$ and $V$ closed in $X$? $U$ is a compact neighborhood of the locally compact Hausdorff subspace $A$, so it is closed in $A$. But does that mean it is closed in $X$?

Comment: @eatfood Every compact subset of a Hausdorff space $X$ is closed in $X$, see, for instance, Engelking’s “General topology”,  Theorems [3.1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74wbJ.png) and [3.1.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omvHs.png).

Comment: I have understood your point, thanks!